Why NodeJS Net::socket.readyState does not change when a connection is disconnected on Linux, but works on Windows?
I am attempting to monitor the status of a NodeJS Net::socket socket connection by periodically polling the .readyState property of the Socket client.  Running the NodeJS app on Windows, this works as expected: I unplug the ethernet cable or change the remote device IP and readyState changes.  Running the same NodeJS app on Linux, the readyState property remains on 'open' and never changes, so I can't reliably determine if the connection is actually open or closed.
Any ideas on how to get around this, and/or a reason for it?  Is there a better way to monitor connection status reliably?
Windows PC: Windows 10 Home V22H2, Node 21.7.1
Linux: Raspbian Bookworm 6.1.74-12781 on Libre AML-S905X-CC SBC, Node 21.7.1

TCP connections are supposed to survive temporary network outages. It is Windows that is wrong here, not Linux.

@user207421 - Can you offer any advice how to detect the true state of the connection reliably on Windows and Linux? thanks

The whole idea of TCP is that there is no 'dial tone', and therefore no 'OK' or 'failure' state to detect. You can only have a failure when you do I/O: read timeout or write error. Anything else is tantamount to trying to predict the future.

@user207421 OK thanks for clarifying. I redesigned the logic to set a counter on failed read/write operations.  If the counter exceeds a set number of errors within a time, it is assumed the connection is down.  Once the error count drops below the threshold, it is assumed the connection is up.

I would take any failure as fatal, not just failures above some threshold > 1.
